# Deploying react frontend & express/nodejs backend on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, knex.js

I have a project on firebase for a front-end React UI deployed just fine, but the back-end nodejs/express app I am trying to deploy with firebase functions is only working locally. Logs say there is an error in the user code but I'm not sure where to even look if it works fine locally. Might be missing something, still new to using tech like firebase so any help would be appreciated, I tried a few different fixes online and it's gotten me this far haha. Code snippets below

root - functions - index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");


const expressApp = express();
const serviceApp = require("../src/app");

expressApp.use(cors());
expressApp.use("/", serviceApp);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(expressApp);
```

root - firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "site": "gys-be-test",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites" : [{"source" : "**", "function" : "app"}]
  }
}
```

root-src-app.js

```
const path = require("path");

require("dotenv").config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "..", ".env") });

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const errorHandler = require("./errors/errorHandler");
const notFound = require("./errors/notFound");


const resourcesRouter = require("./Resources/resources.router");
const contactsRouter = require("./Contacts/contacts.router");
const postsRouter = require("./Posts/posts.router");
const usersRouter = require("./Users/users.router");
const promptsRouter = require("./Prompts/prompts.router");
const eventsRouter = require("./Events/events.router");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/posts", postsRouter);
app.use("/prompts", promptsRouter);
app.use("/events", eventsRouter);
app.use("/resources", resourcesRouter);
// app.use("/downloads", downloadsRouter);
// app.use("/media", mediaRouter);
app.use("/contacts", contactsRouter);

app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);


module.exports = app;
```

root-src-server.js

```
const { PORT = 5001 } = process.env;

const app = require("./app");
const knex = require("./db/connection");

knex.migrate
  .latest()
  .then((migrations) => {
    console.log("migrations", migrations);
    app.listen(PORT, listener);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    knex.destroy();
  });

function listener() {
  console.log(`Listening on Port ${PORT}!`);
}
```

and a snippet from the firebase debug log

```
[info] Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    app(us-central1)
[debug] [2022-09-04T20:22:06.986Z] Not printing URL for HTTPS function. Typically this means it didn't match a filter or we failed deployment
[info] i  functions: cleaning up build files... 
[debug] [2022-09-04T20:22:06.988Z] >>> [apiv2][query] DELETE https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/gys-be-test/locations/us-central1/repositories/gcf-artifacts/packages/app [none]
[debug] [2022-09-04T20:22:06.989Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/gys-be-test/gcf/us-central1/tags/list [none]
[debug] [2022-09-04T20:22:07.199Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/gys-be-test/gcf/us-central1/tags/list 200
[debug] [2022-09-04T20:22:07.199Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/gys-be-test/gcf/us-central1/tags/list {"child":[],"manifest":{},"name":"gys-be-test/gcf/us-central1","tags":[]}
[debug] [2022-09-04T20:22:07.200Z] Could not find image for function projects/gys-be-test/locations/us-central1/functions/app
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to welcome you to StackOverflow.

I think it look weird with the exports.app in the first snippet, I personally don't understand why it is not exports.module, can you confirm this is intentional before we continue?